# Solution... 2nd Transcendental Equation with Graphical method

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

If $ 2x^3 + \ln x = 5 $, then what is $ x $?

For beginning we started to find a solution for equation

$$
\begin{align}\label{eq:eq}
\ln x + cx = b \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

We know from W function that $ ax\mathrm e^{ax} = y \Rightarrow ax = W(k, y) $, where $ k \in \mathbb Z $.
From Eq. \ref{eq:eq}
$$
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow \ln(ax) + ax &= \ln y \\
\Rightarrow \ln x + x &= \ln(y/a) \label{eq:eq2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

From Eqs. \ref{eq:eq} and \ref{eq:eq2}

=>a=c & Log(y/a)=b.Then y=a*e^(b) & x=1/a*W(k,a*e^(b))..k in Z.(3).If now we take the original equation Log x+2*x^3=5 we do the transformation …x^3=z (5) =>3*Log(x)=Log(z)+2kπi =>x=z^(1/3)*e^(2k’πi/3)..k’ in Z (6) Βut with the transformation(5) the relation (1) is done Log(z)+6z=15.. (7).But the relation (7) has solution in accordance with the foregoing z=1/6*W(k,6e^(15))..(8) ,k in Z.From (6&8) we have the filnal solution =>

x=(1/6*W(k,6e^(15)))^(1/3)*e^(2k’πi/3) ,k&k’ in Z.
The solutions are 3 only …

1…with k=0 & k’=0,…,x=1.33084 ,,,Real
and we have 2 complex roots
2.. for k=1 & k’=2 =>x=-0.520715 - 1.26144 I and
3.. for k=-1 & k’=-2 =>x=-0.520715 + 1.26144 I

Comment: Τhanks Αλέξανδρος for formatting!!!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Solve[2 x^3 + Log[x] == 5, x] 
(*{{x -> (1/6 ProductLog[6 E^15])^(1/3)}}*)
```

What you cal "W-function" is Mathematica ProductLog!

Comment: Yes ,,, you are right, it is simply called and so...Τhanks  ..Sure it has and complex Roots!!!

Comment: Graphical Method........in Mathematica!!!                                                                                  
f[x_] = 2 x^3 + Log[x] - 5;
Normal[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]] /. 
 p_Point :> {p, Text[Style[p[[1, 1]], 14], {0, 5} + p[[1]]]}

Comment: The complex roots is ONLY 3 because for any case 0<=k’<=2!!!

Comment: W-function is ProductLog()

Answer (score 0):

FindInstance can locate all three roots:

```
FindInstance[2 x^3 + Log[x] == 5, x, 3] // N

{{x -> -0.520715 - 1.26144 I}, {x -> 1.33084}, {x -> -0.520715 + 1.26144 I}}
```

Alternatively, FindRoot can find all three, though you have to help it with different starting points:

```
FindRoot[2 x^3 + Log[x] == 5, {x, #}] & /@ {1, -1 + I, -1 - I}

{{x -> 1.33084}, {x -> -0.520715 + 1.26144 I}, {x -> -0.520715 - 1.26144 I}}
```

Comment: Yes it is correct!!!

Answer (score 0):

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) or [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) will give all three roots if you constrain the [`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) value of `x`

```
Solve[{2 x^3 + Log[x] == 5, Abs[x] < 2}, x]
```

[image]

```
{{x -> Root[{-5 + Log[#1] + 
       2 #1^3 &, \
-0.52071466111311432025020844963466209285486182967411316474958 - 
      1.26143852926442301838345194738901835961144796731648927183682 I}]}, {x \
-> Root[{-5 + Log[#1] + 
       2 #1^3 &, \
-0.52071466111311432025020844963466209285486182967411316474958 + 
      1.26143852926442301838345194738901835961144796731648927183682 I}]}, {x \
-> Root[{-5 + Log[#1] + 2 #1^3 &, 1.33083954213436297147435824439}]}}
```

Comment: You dont know Abs[x]<2,,FROM WHERE?